How can I find KDEConnect dbus message data structure?
I'm running KDEConnect on a Linux system and my Android phone. I want to be able to programatically fetch my SMS messages, which is not a current feature of KDEConnect cli program.
I am able to fetch all messages by using dbus with the following command:
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.kdeconnect /modules/kdeconnect/devices/$(dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.kdeconnect /modules/kdeconnect/devices org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect | sed -n 's/.*node name="\(.*\)".*/\1/p') org.kde.kdeconnect.device.conversations.activeConversations

This returns an array of message structs in the following form:
      variant          struct {
            int32 3
            string "Some message"
            array [
               struct {
                  string "+phone number"
               }
               struct {
                  string "+phone number"
               }
            ]
            int64 1680712299000
            int32 1
            int32 1
            int64 152
            int32 2461
            int64 1
            array [
            ]
         }

Is there a way to find out what all of these fields are? I've tried looking
into the KDEConnect source, but haven't had much luck. The phone numbers, message, timestamp, and attachment array (empty in this example) are clear, but I'm not sure about the other fields. I especially would like some sort of thread ID or similar.
Edit
I can also fetch this information in Python, but I get it as a dbus struct which extends the Python tuple class, thus has no labels for fields.
I have also found that I am not fetching all messages this way, but the first message of all threads. Ideally, I'd like to fetch all messages from all threads.

You can check the cpp structure of that message from the KDE Connect repository
    ConversationMessage(const qint32 &eventField,
                        const QString &body,
                        const QList<ConversationAddress> &addresses,
                        const qint64 &date,
                        const qint32 &type,
                        const qint32 &read,
                        const qint64 &threadID,
                        const qint32 &uID,
                        const qint64 &subID,
                        const QList<Attachment> &attachments);

Source: https://github.com/KDE/kdeconnect-kde/blob/master/interfaces/conversationmessage.cpp

Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.
